# WebServcie data return XML format issue

Tags: java, apache-axis

When I call the other party's webService interface, the resulting XML data format is as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <response>
         <traceId>abf95b6d1d704aa9977a8887159ff3ce</traceId>
         <code>E00000</code>
         <message>请求成功！</message>
         <data>
            <item>
               <BAH>282444</BAH>
               <ZYID>2824447</ZYID>
               <SBM_EMR>179968</SBM_EMR>
               <ZYCS>7</ZYCS>
               <ZDMC>恶性胸腔积液</ZDMC>
               <ZDICD>C78.201</ZDICD>
               <RYBQ/>
               <ZDLB>cy</ZDLB>
               <XH>0</XH>
            </item>
            <item>
               <BAH>282444</BAH>
               <ZYID>2824447</ZYID>
               <SBM_EMR>179968</SBM_EMR>
               <ZYCS>7</ZYCS>
               <ZDMC>肺恶性肿瘤（Iv期）</ZDMC>
               <ZDICD>C34.900x001</ZDICD>
               <RYBQ/>
               <ZDLB>zy</ZDLB>
               <XH>0</XH>
            </item>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

May I know the specific type I should use to accept it? It keeps reporting errors similar to serialization to me

I have tried using String type acceptance, but it is not very feasible

```
call.setReturnType(XMLType.XSD_STRING);
result = (String) call.invoke(new Object[]{headerTemp.toString(),contentTemp.toString()});
```